# Significance of circulation of vector field

Tags: vector-analysis, physics, mathematical-physics, vector-fields, mathematical-modeling

Is there any direct significance, physical or otherwise, of the circulation of a vector field (when *not* connecting it to the curl)?

Every application, problem, example, or physical model of circulation I've seen has to do with curl.  But is there ever a case that the circulation itself is of interest?

Interestingly, if the vector field is a fluid velocity field, in units of $m/s$, then the circulation is in units $m^2/s$, suggesting that it is some sort of area per time.  But I can find no example or model that explains how circulation should be viewed as an area per time.

Comment: It’s the work done by the force field moving a test object once around the path. The units make more sense with force than velocity.

Comment: @TedShifrin In that case, a force field, circulation is simply a line integral where we happen to end up where we started.  That seems like a redundant concept, because we could just use line integrals.  Given that, and the fact that for a velocity flow there doesn't seem to be any useful model of circulation, should I accept "Circulation is a useful _mathematical_ concept because a) for some fields it is always 0 and b) it relates to curl.  But it doesn't have a direct meaning.  We calculate it because it's useful to figure _other things_ out, not because we're ever interested in it per se."?

Comment: I think the name is reasonable if you think of the force inducing spinning of a wire (say in the case of a circular path); then the work tells you the energy transfer and hence the change in angular velocity.  None of this requires mentioning curl.

Comment: Curl is just the pointwise measure of circulation. Claiming circulation is redundant is similar to claiming "area" is redundant since we can just use integrals of width. Just as width measures the size of a region at one height. while area measures its overall size; curl measures the twisting of a vector field at one point, while circulation is the measure of its overall twisting.

Comment: @PaulSinclair To clarify, I am not suggesting that circulation is redundant since we have curl, but rather asking how circulation is used at all.  Circulation doesn't seem to be a measure of _overall twisting_, as you write, but rather _overall twisting * length over which the twist happens_, a quantity which I'm not able to understand its _direct inherent_ significance (of course, it has _mathematical_ significance due to the theorems and calculations - the question if it is has direct significance.)